# Issue trying to change ImageView in List Activity

Tags: android, image, listview, drawable

I am having problems when I try to alter the image in a list view.

Below is the layout XML for the row in the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="left">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flagIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:src="@drawable/orange_flag"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_row_item_main_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_row_item_secondary_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Runs ok and shows the drawable stated (i.e. orange_flag), but this doesn't change when I try and alter it in the following code:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter { 

    // In your ListActivity class, create a new inner class that extends ResourceCursorAdapter. 
    //This inner class is the custom CursorAdapter we will use to manage how data is bound to a list item:

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) { 
        super(context, R.layout.row_location, cursor);
    } 

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) { 
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_row_item_main_text);
        title.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.RACKING_SYSTEM)));
        ImageView flagIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flagIcon);
        String risk = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.RISK));
        if (risk == "Red Risk"){
            flagIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_flag);
        }
        else if (risk == "Green Risk"){
            flagIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_flag);
        }
        else if (risk =="No Risk"){
            flagIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.note);
        }
```

Any ideas?!

Comment: That is it - thank you Wingman.  Much appreciated - if you want to plonk into an answer I'll give you a tick!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` when comparing String data type for the contents.

For strings in java:

- `==` compares whether strings are *same Object* or not.
- `equals()` compares whether strings have *same sequence of characters* or not.

Comment: Just to make sure "StRIng" is compared with "sTriNG" and returns true, This method ignores Lower case and upper case differences.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `flagIcon.invalidate()` after setting the resource.

Comment: Thank you for quick response Blumer, but that didn't work (I tried flagIcon.invalidate(); by the way as invalide wasn't accepted).  Any other ideas?

Comment: In light of wingman's good point, can you put a Log statement in there to confirm that the code setting the ImageResouce is indeed being reached? Also, what happens if you try getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_flag) instead of setImageResource()?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying

```
flagIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_flag);
```

You can try this :

```
flagIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_flag);
```